# Appending model data to table in ember.js app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My application is fairly simple. There is a navbar that has a set of categories, upon clicking the category a table is put into the outlet. What I'd like to happen is depending on which category is clicked, certain data is picked and then appended to the empty table in outlet.

Example:
(category from navbar)

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="category1">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
      {{#each}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{data_1}}</td>
          <td>{{data_2}}</td>
          <td>{{data_3}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
  </script>
```

and then in app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Category1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return category1_data;
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('category1');
});

var category1_data = [
  {
    data_1: 'test data name',
    data_2: 1,
    data_3: 'more data
  }
]
```

However now I am currently copying that table for each of my 9 categories which isn't very DRY. Is there a way to no be as repetitive in displaying this data?

Comment: Have you tried Ember partials?

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for/worked like a charm